# How to exclude some (not all) record that has same values

Tags: sql, sql-server

After query table A using first query, I have these records:

```
pID  cID   code
1     1     A 
1     1     B 
1     1     B 
1     1     B
```

After query table B using second query, I have one record:

```
pID   cID   code
1     1     B 
1     1     B
```

I want table A exclude the records of table B. The result is:

```
pID   cID   code
1     1     A
1     1     A
```

How can I do that? Hope u could help me. thanks. 
***Updating...*** 

Sorry for the example to make you confuse 
If I got these record from second table:

```
pID   cID   code
1     1     B
```

Then the result I want is (exclude one record):

```
pID  cID   code
1     1     A 
1     1     B 
1     1     B
```

Comment: please add your query--

Comment: What about `select * from tableA union select * from tableB;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use EXCEPT. How ever your desired output is wrong as 1  1  B also the same record from TableB

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
```

Refer this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188055.aspx)

If your case NOt all But some then.

Simply you can use DISTINCT

As per the UPdate in Question (From what I understood)

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE_A
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
```

Comment: you mention "union" but your query is using "except"

Comment: Sorry to make you confuse, I updated the question and example :)

Comment: No issue. I have updated my answer. It may be suits your case but not 100% as question is still incomplete. Thank you @hoang

Answer (score 0):

you try **[GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)** function in your Query
example :

```
select pID,cID,code  from table group by code
```

Answer (score 0):

using EXCEPT and row_number() to generate a unique no

```
;with cte1 as
(
    select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by pID, cID, code order by pID, cID, code)
    from    query1
),
cte2 as
(
    select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by pID, cID, code order by pID, cID, code)
    from    query2
)
select  *
from    cte1
except
select  *
from    cte2
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, which I think you want to delete the records from B which occur more than once in A:

first select all records from A which are not there in B and then union them 1 distinct records which are there in both A and B:

```
select * from A
except 
select * from B

union all

select distinct *
from
  (select a.pid, a.cid, a.code
   from 
   A
   inner join 
   B
   on a.pid=b.pid and a.cid=b.cid and a.code=b.code)
```